# Marker positioning in Linear Bounded Automata

Tags: computation-theory, finite-automata

So, we recently discussed the topic of Linear Bounded Automata in class, but we didn't exactly define them formally. After looking up definitions online, I am still confused about the positioning of the markers. Are they always supposed to lie at either end of the input string? Can they be further to the left/right, just as long as their distance is at most some constant multiple of the length of the input? If so, do we get to choose their position for every input string separately (for example, making sure the left marker is always right before the input string)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The linear bounded automaton is a restricted form of a nondeterministic Turing machine. The restriction is that the tape is **finite**. That is ensured by limiting the tape in its both ends with **markers**. That is all about it.

Now, how you choose these markers is not relevant for the automaton, as far as distance from the left and the right markers (i.e. the length of the tape) is a linear function of the input's length.

The Turing machine starts with a tape that has the input written in it "somewhere", and the tape's head points to its first symbol. The LBA does not add new restrictions on that, so it remains: the input is somewhere. That implies (because of the limitation markers) that the input is **between** the two markers, you can place your input's first symbol just after the left marker or place the input's last symbol just before the right marker. Both cases are not forbidden by the definition of LBA.

How the different position of the input on the tape will be used by the automaton with its states is another topic. With other words, you might need a specific placement of the input on the tape that depends from the automaton states and transition, else you will not get an acceptance.